# Disable button and display div on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have a form where upon clicking the submit button, it should submit the form, disable the submit button, and display a processing message. Everything works great in Chrome, Firefox, & IE. In Safari it just submits the form, disables the button, and does not display the processing message. This is the jQuery I am using:

```
$('#review').on('submit', function() {
    $(this).find('.submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
    $("#processing").slideDown("slow");
});
```

Comment: You haven't supplied the relevant HTML or CSS so we can't confirm that `#processing` is not hidden in such a way that `slideDown()` wouldn't affect. or that the HTML is valid, or that you're actually preventing/deferring the form from posting which might be the issue with Safari.

Comment: @Popnoodles If it didn't exist, how would it work in other browsers?

Comment: Try swapping the statements `$("#processing").slideDown("slow");   $(this).find('.submit').attr('disabled','disabled');`

Comment: There was a question a week or so ago like this, but I don't remember if there was a solution. The issue is that reloading the page when the form is submitted cancels running scripts.

Comment: That's what I suspected Barmar. @awsm try preventing the form from posting (`preventDefault()`) and see if the animation works then. If so it's Safari cancelling scripts on post. You could `show()` instead or defer the submission if it's that important to `slideDown()`.

Answer (score 0):

refer http://api.jquery.com/submit/

```
$('#review').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('.submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
    $("#processing").slideDown("slow");
});
```